# Transaction isolation level sets to Serializable by itself when using Mono and Postgresql on linux

Tags: c#, linux, postgresql, mono

I have a project that should work on linux using Mono and PostgreSQL. In my project I write the following code:

```
var opt = new TransactionOptions();
opt.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
opt.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, opt))
    {
        using (TContext context = Resolve())
        {
        context.Database.Connection.Open();               
        context.Database.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
        // Some actions
        context.SaveChanges();

        }
        tx.Complete();
    }
```

When I run this code on Windows in logs for PostgreSQL I see that every transaction was executed with ReadCommited isolation level.

But when I execute exact the same code on linux in Mono using the same database it shows me that isolation level was Serializable.

I have a suspicion, that mono has some problems with transactionScope.

Why is this a problem? I ran the following test. I started the code that changes the lastname of  50 000 users in for loop on 3 differnet machines at the same time. When I run test on Windows it works fine. But on Linux - does not. The error says "An error occurred while updatingthe entries. Could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions".

Comment: Does https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28053 help?